# How do I create this view in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, view, syntax

Sorry, I'm new MySql user.

I'm trying to create this view, but MySql does not accept this format. Could you help me create it?

```
{CREATE VIEW VWBALANCO(
    CODCONTA,
    NOMECONTA,
    TIPO,
    CONTACREDITO,
    CONTADEBITO,
    CONTAGERENCIAL,
    DATA,
    CODIGREJA,
    NOMEIGREJA,
    CODEPARTAMENTO,
    NOMEDEPARTAMENTO,
    VLRPAGAMENTO,
    VLRECEBIMENTO)
AS
select BL.CODCONTA,BL.NOMECONTA,CT.TIPO,CT.CONTACREDITO,CT.CONTADEBITO,CT.CONTAGERENCIAL,BL.DATA,BL.CODIGREJA,BL.NOMEIGREJA,BL.CODDEPARTAMENTO,BL.NOMEDEPARTAMENTO,sum(BL.VLRPAGAMENTO),sum(BL.VLRECEBIMENTO) from MOVBALANCETE BL inner join CONTAS CT on CT.CODIGO = BL.CODCONTA 
group by BL.CODCONTA, BL.NOMECONTA, CT.TIPO, CT.CONTACREDITO, CT.CONTADEBITO, CT.CONTAGERENCIAL, BL.DATA,BL.CODIGREJA,BL.NOMEIGREJA,BL.CODDEPARTAMENTO,BL.NOMEDEPARTAMENTO,BL.VLRPAGAMENTO,BL.VLRECEBIMENTO;}
```

If anyone can enlighten me where I am going wrong in the syntax. 
This syntax is typically used in Firebird Database.

Thank you!

Comment: What are the curly braces?  These are probably your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
CREATE VIEW VWBALANCO
AS
select BL.CODCONTA,BL.NOMECONTA,CT.TIPO,CT.CONTACREDITO,CT.CONTADEBITO,CT.CONTAGERENCIAL,BL.DATA,BL.CODIGREJA,BL.NOMEIGREJA,BL.CODDEPARTAMENTO,BL.NOMEDEPARTAMENTO,sum(BL.VLRPAGAMENTO),sum(BL.VLRECEBIMENTO) from MOVBALANCETE BL inner join CONTAS CT on CT.CODIGO = BL.CODCONTA 
group by BL.CODCONTA, BL.NOMECONTA, CT.TIPO, CT.CONTACREDITO, CT.CONTADEBITO, CT.CONTAGERENCIAL, BL.DATA,BL.CODIGREJA,BL.NOMEIGREJA,BL.CODDEPARTAMENTO,BL.NOMEDEPARTAMENTO,BL.VLRPAGAMENTO,BL.VLRECEBIMENTO;
```

ie, remove the column name

Comment: Thanks RT,MySql can not accept nicknames in the selection, for example: "CONTAS" CT, so I had to remove them. 

Here's how: "select BALANCETE.CODCONTA,BALANCETE.NOMECONTA,CONTAS.TIPO..from MOVBALANCETE inner join CONTAS on CONTAS.CODIGO = BALANCETE.CODCONTA..."